# Can I rewrite from subdomain to folder avoiding redirection?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, subdomain

I want my subdomain to point directly to a folder.
That is if an HTTP request is made to apple.example.com,
I want the response to be the contents of example.com/apple/index.html, but not a 301 error.
Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is exactly the purpose of tools like ISAPI_REWRITE. My hosting company (orcsweb) uses exactly this technique.

-OIsin

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but you need to make sure that your server is able to support virtual domains.  I don't know enough about this, but the mod_rewrite is possible without redirects.

Answer (score 0):

```
# Internally rewrite <subdomain>.example.com/<URLpath> to example.com/subs/<subdomain/<URLpath>
RewriteCond $1 !^subs/
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.example\.com
RewriteRule (.*) /subs/%1/$1 [L]
```

Comment: I have already found this solution on the net.
But it does not work for me.
The following error is displayed in the browser when I navigate to apple.example.com
----
Not Found
The requested URL / was not found on this server.

Answer (score 0):

You can serve content from any folder or you can send a redirect to the client, but AFAIK you cannot do both at the same time - you cannot serve content and somehow change the url in browser at the same time.

If it would be possible, it would most definitely lead to many security exploits.