# Why subdomain rewrite does not work?

Tags: mod-rewrite

I want my subdomain to point directly to a folder.
I have found the following mod_rewrite script to setup this behavior.
Unfortunately it does not work.

When I navigate to fish.example.com, the browser displays 404 error with the following message.
"The requested URL / was not found on this server."

Do you know why?
How can I make it work?

```
    # Internally rewrite <subdomain>.example.com/<URLpath> to example.com/subs/<subdomain/<URLpath>
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond $1 !^fish/
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.example\.com
RewriteRule (.*) /fish/%1/$1 [L]
```

**UPDATE**

I have changed the script to the following, but in this case the browser redirects to example.com instead of example.com/fish
Do you know why?

```
RewriteCond $1 !^fish/
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.example\.com
RewriteRule ^fish/(.*) /fish/%1/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Does the Apache access/error logs give you any useful information?

Comment: Yes Michael, thank you for the tip.
I see the following message 
[Tue Oct 13 09:21:05 2009] [error] [client 188.134.xxx.xxx] File does not exist: /var/www/fish/fish

Looks like the dir is added 2 times. But I have no idea why.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1555390/can-i-rewrite-from-subdomain-to-folder-avoiding-redirection

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

RewriteEngine On

Rewrite Base /  # Make sure it starts from the domain

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^fish.example.com [NC]   # Catch your subdomain

RewriteRule (.*)$ fish/$1 [L]     # Reroute to folder.

Comment: Thanks, Brent!
Unfortunately it does not work.
Apache says there is a syntax error in RewriteBase line.
RewriteBase / # Make sure it starts from the domain
Yes I write it without the space between Rewrite and Base, but it does not help. Still have the error.

Answer (score 0):

Update:

I see... try this:

```
RewriteCond $1 !^fish/
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.example\.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://example.com/%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Basically a 301 redirect... %1 matches the subdomain in the previous RewriteCond, and $1 matches the original url

Comment: John, I have changed the script the way you propose, but in this case the browser redirects to example.com instead of example.com/fish
See the full script in my update to the topic.